# How do i get the latest cookie using js?

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can i get the latest cookie sent from a domain ?

eg : 
cookies 
1 - ABC
2 - ABC123
3 - ABC456

These 3 cookies has been sent from a domain, how do i find which one is the latest one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cookie_attributes):

> Beside the name/value pair, a cookie
>   may also contain an expiration date, a
>   path, a domain name, and whether the
>   cookie is intended only for encrypted
>   connections. RFC 2965 also specifies
>   that cookies must have a mandatory
>   version number, but this is usually
>   omitted.

So you can:

- Check the version number, if there is one
- Check the expiration date, assuming it's being set based on current time + some amount

As far as I know, that's all you can do. If you're involved in setting the cookie, you can put the information you need into one of the properties above when you set it.

Comment: I was writing the same answer